# NSBundle pathForResource nil

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsbundle

I am attempting to load an M4A file but I can't get the path to the file using NSBundle.

```
NSString *fileURLString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:fileExtension];
NSURL *fileToBePlayed = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:fileURLString];

tourAudioPlayer = [tourAudioPlayer initWithContentsOfURL:fileToBePlayed error:nil];
```

When I run the code the debugger shows that fileURLString is nil and, thus, so are the subsequent two objects.

I've added the file to the *Supporting Files* directory and confirmed that the file is included under Copy Bundle Resources under Target > Build Phases.

Unfortunately the magic of Clean and Build has failed me in this case. Is there some stage in loading the file in that I'm missing?

Comment: Could you show what's values in `fileName` or `fileExtension`?

Comment: Sometimes Xcode gets very confused with external files added to your project, and you can sometimes remedy it by completely removing app from device/simulator and reinstalling. Also, if doing this in a device, are you sure about the capitalization of the file name (as device is case sensitive)? As an aside, if I wanted a URL, I'd use `URLForResource`, to save going from path to URL, but clearly that's not the issue here...

Comment: Check the bundle to see if the file is in it. It should be within ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications.

Comment: I removed the app from the simulator. This had the affect that the fileURLString is no longer null and now points to the bundle in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/etc. Unfortunately the NSURL itself is still nil.

I've confirmed that the file is indeed located where it should be in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications.

The fileName is "dholaks" and the fileExtension is "m4a".

Answer (score 0):

Just try this....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *vedioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:FileName ofType:FileType]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:vedioURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerView];
    [videoPlayerView.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, which turns out to have been two silly problems.

The first problem was that I was using initWithString: rather than fileURLWithPath:. Lazy reading of the documentation on my part.

The second problem was a mere embarrassing oversight. The code snippet provided represents the initial creation of the AVAudioPlayer and thus I was following to allocate space for it on the heap.

Making the changes above has remedied the problem. Thank you to everyone that offered advice and support.